# Can't retrieve binding context

Tags: sapui5

I need to be able to retrieve binding context + path from StandardListItem in a list.

However, `getBindingContext()` returns undefined...

I've search for the `oBindingContexts` property with `oSource` of `oEvent` and and it is there.

```js
onJobPress: function(oEvent) {
  var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
  var oBindingContext = oSource.getBindingContext(); // undefined
  var oPath = oBindingContext.getPath(); // error
  var data = oBindingContext.getProperty(oPath); // error
  // ...
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the binding context of clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556515/how-to-get-the-binding-context-of-clicked-item)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a named model? Then it would be:

```
oSource.getBindingContext("modelName");
```